# MEAN stack project issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

when i run in my localhost then my PC is stuck or it's hang all the processes.

Also when i upload it on AWS server then also server slow down.

Anyone have an idea why this happened?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am not even sure what you are talking about please share your troubled code with question too Thanks.

Comment: When i run MEAN stack Project, angular-cli on my localhost or even on server localhost/serve both are hangs.